How can I put the maximum stress on the CPU without using vectorized instructions?
I am testing the characteristics of the CPU frequency fluctuation between the turbo max and the base frequency. Therefore, I want a load that can force the CPU to reduce its frequency from turbo to base when the whole machine load reaches 100%.
I am currently using the famous Prime95, which can produce a heavy load, but the latest version cannot generate a non-vectorized load on x86_64 machines, at least SSE2 instructions are used, which is not in line with my needs.
Are there scalar instruction-based stress testing programs that can generate a significant load on the CPU and cause the frequency to drop?
I have tested stress-ng's CPU load, but none of them is heavy enough to cause the CPU to drop to the base frequency.
